# How to check multidimensional arrays for the given key value pairs ie. exactly same keys and values?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, laravel-5, logic

when compared with the main array it should return the matching keys of the main array

For example:

```
$a = array(
   'a' => array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value1', 'key3' => 'value1'),
   'b' => array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value2'), 
   'c' => array('key1' => 'value3', 'key2' => 'value3', 'key3' => 'value3'),
   'd' => array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value4')
);


1: $search1 = array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2');
```

when comparing with above array search1 it should return key 'b' and 'd'

ie. ['b','d']

```
    2: $search2 = array('key1' => 'value3', 'key3' => 'value3');
```

when comparing with above array search2 it should return key 'c'

ie. ['c']

```
    3: $search3 = array('key1' => 'value3', 'key2' => 'value3', 'key3' => 'value3' );
```

when comparing with above array search3 it should return key 'c'

ie. ['c']

```
    4: $search4 = array('key1' => 'value2');
```

when comparing with above array search4 it should return key 'b' and 'd'

ie. ['b','d']

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_intersect_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php), something like:

```
function compareArrays($x, $y){
  $output = []; // Create an empty array to hold the output

  foreach($x as $key => $value): // Loop array $x as key/value
    if (count(array_intersect_assoc($y, $value)) > 0) { // Check if the intersection is greater than 0
      $output[] = $key; // If so, push the key to $output
    }
  endforeach;

  print_r($output); // Do something with the output
}
```

The above function takes 2 arguments, being the 2 arrays you want to compare. The first array is the master array. It outputs an array of items that don't match the first argument. A more complete example:

```
$a = array(
   'a' => array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value1', 'key3' => 'value1'),
   'b' => array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value2'), 
   'c' => array('key1' => 'value3', 'key2' => 'value3', 'key3' => 'value3'),
   'd' => array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value4')
);

$search1 = array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2');
$search2 = array('key1' => 'value3', 'key3' => 'value3');
$search3 = array('key1' => 'value3', 'key2' => 'value3', 'key3' => 'value3' );
$search4 = array('key1' => 'value2');

function compareArrays($x, $y){
  $output = [];

  foreach($x as $key => $value):
    if (count(array_intersect_assoc($y, $value)) > 0) {
      $output[] = $key;
    }
  endforeach;

  print_r($output);
}

compareArrays($a, $search1); // b,d
compareArrays($a, $search2); // c
compareArrays($a, $search3); // c
compareArrays($a, $search4); // b,d
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/5JrcY)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$output =array(
'a' => array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value1', 'key3' => 'value1'),
'b' => array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value2'), 
'c' => array('key1' => 'value3', 'key2' => 'value3', 'key3' => 'value3'),
'd' => array('key1' => 'value2', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value4')
);

$res = [];
$search = array('key1' => 'value2');

foreach($output as $key => $out)
{
if(isset($search['key1']) && isset($search['key2']) && !array_key_exists('key3',$search))
{
    if($search['key1'] == $out['key1'] && $search['key2'] == $out['key2'])
    {
        $res[] = $key;
    }
}
if(isset($search['key1']) && isset($search['key3']) && !array_key_exists('key2',$search))
{
    if($search['key1'] == $out['key1'] && $search['key3'] == $out['key3'])
    {
        $res[] = $key;
    }
}
if(isset($search['key2']) && isset($search['key3']) && !array_key_exists('key1',$search))
{
    if($search['key2'] == $out['key2'] && $search['key3'] == $out['key3'])
    {
        $res[] = $key;
    }
}
if(!array_key_exists('key1',$search) && !array_key_exists('key2',$search) && isset($search['key3']))
{
   if($search['key3'] == $out['key3'])
    {
        $res[] = $key;
    } 
}
if(!array_key_exists('key2',$search) && !array_key_exists('key3',$search)&& isset($search['key1']))
{
   if($search['key1'] == $out['key1'])
    {
        $res[] = $key;
    } 
}
if(!array_key_exists('key1',$search) && !array_key_exists('key3',$search)&& isset($search['key2']))
{
   if($search['key2'] == $out['key2'])
    {
        $res[] = $key;
    } 
}
if(isset($search['key1']) && isset($search['key2']) && isset($search['key3']))
{
    if($search['key1'] == $out['key1'] && $search['key2'] == $out['key2'] && $search['key3'] == $out['key3'])
    {
        $res[] = $key;
    }
}
}
print_r($res);die();
```

change `$search` with the test conditions to get result...